# Protractor Customized Reporting

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

Am using Protractor Jasmine Framework along with jasmine allure reporter.Please give clarifications for following:

1. is reporter pass/fail steps is only based on `describe` `it` blocks only?
2. Am using multiple steps inside a `it` block. How can we add test step without 
   using `it` blocks? Like each and every step needs to be reported.
3. How can we print a passed `expect` statement in html file reporter?

Comment: why are you using multiple steps inside 'it' blocks, they are meant to have one step/one basis test case?

Comment: if you need to cover multiple steps then bundle them as single function in side page object and call it from spec file as a single step inside 'it' block.

Answer (score -1):

You can use chaining to have multiple condition in an `it` block.

```
    it("checks URLs redirect to data browser after deletion.", function () {
            var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
                modalTitle = modalInstance.recordPage.getConfirmDeleteTitle(),
                config, redirectUrl;

            browser.executeScript('return configObject;').then(function(configObject) {
                config = configObject;
                return modalInstance.recEditPage.getDeleteRecordButton().click()
            }).then(function () {
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(modalTitle), browser.params.defaultTimeout);
                // expect modal to open
                return modalTitle.getText();
            }).then(function (text) {
                expect(text).toBe("Confirm Delete!!");

                return modalInstance.recPage.getConfirmDeleteButton().click();
            }).then(function () {
                redirectUrl = "https://test/xyz";

                browser.wait(function () {
                    return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                        return url.startsWith(redirectUrl);
                    })
                });

                return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();
            }).then(function (url) {
                expect(url.startsWith(redirectUrl)).toBe(true);

            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.dir(error);
                expect(error).not.toBeDefined();
            });;
        });
```

I use [jasmin-spec-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) for reporting.

Comment: I would not suggest to  expose any low level programming logic in spec files.Spec files are meant to provide business/domain level view of the functionality.It should read like as much as possible as a well defined manual test case.